# How to delete data from ElasticSearch through JavaAPI

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

EDITED
I'm trying to find out how to delete data from Elasticsearch according to a criteria. I know that older versions of ElasticSearch had Delete By Query feature, but it had really serious performance issues, so it was removed. I know also for that there is a Java plugin for delete by query:

org.elasticsearch.plugin:delete-by-query:2.2.0

But I don't know if it has a better implementation of delete which has a better performance or it's the same as the old one.

Also, someone suggested using scroll to remove data, but I know how to retrieve data scrolling, not how to use scroll to remove!

Does anyone have an idea (the amount of documents to remove in a call would be huge, over 50k documents.

Thanks in advance!

Finally used this [guy's third option](https://midgetontoes.com/elasticsearch-delete-documents-by-type/)

Comment: Are you using ES 2.2.0 ?

Comment: ES 1.7 something, and java API is 2.3.5

Comment: I don't know, for instance, how to do something like this:

curl -XDELETE localhost:9200/_search/scroll -d '
{
    "scroll_id" : ["c2Nhbjs2OzM0NDg1ODpzRlBLc0FXNlNyNm5JWUc1"]
}'

but with the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that you want to use the scroll/scan.  Here are the steps:

1. begin a new scroll/scan
2. Get next N records
3. Take the IDs from each record and do a BulkDelete of those IDs
4. go back to step 2

So you don't delete exactly using the scroll/scan, you just use that as a tool to get all the IDs for the records that you want to delete.  In this way you're only deleting N records at a time and not all 50,000 in 1 chunk (which would cause you all kinds of problems).

Comment: I did exactly that, thanks a lot! And sorry for delay replying!